# Print Object / Instance of Class in Python

Tags: python

Deck is class with attribute "deck" which is list. This list contains cards. cards is also an object of class Card with attribute suit and rank..

How can I print instance / object **deck** of class Deck?

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))
```

Comment: the same way you print anything, with `print(instance)`, e.g. `print(Deck())`

Answer (score 0):

You should override **repr**() or **str**() function. It depends python version. 
You can write that you want see data.
Then you can use **print(Deck()**) or **print(instance)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this function into you class definition, you can change it for what style you want.

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.deck)
```

Answer (score 0):

on the line after that, use a print function on deck

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))
        print(self.deck)
```

Then whenever that code is run, which it will be whenever you make a new Deck, it will print deck after